# How to install PyTorch for Real-Time-Voice-Cloning on Windows?

Tags: python, pytorch, conda

I've got the following problem: I want to install [CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning](https://github.com/CorentinJ/Real-Time-Voice-Cloning) but there's a problem with PyTorch. Here's what I've done already:

- downloaded the Real-Time-Voice-Cloning repository
- downloaded the pre-trained models into the encoder, vocoder and synthesizer folder
- installed ffmpeg
- successfully ran `pip install -r requirements.txt`
- installed Anaconda
- successfully installed PyTorch using `conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch`

However, when checking the installation using `python demo_cli.py` I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

Then, I tried installing PyTorch with Pip using the following command I got on https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally:

```
pip3 install torch==1.8.1+cpu torchvision==0.9.1+cpu torchaudio===0.8.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

But I got the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.8.1+cpu (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.8.1+cpu
```

Also, I tried just `pip3 install torch` (and `pip install torch`) but got the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'`. I was able to install `tools` but didn't succeed in installing `nnwrap`.

What can I do to make Real-Time-Voice-Cloning work? Do I ***have to*** use CUDA for PyTorch to work?

My Python version: 3.7.4

Answer (score 0):

You may install cpu only pytorch and vocoder,synthesizer , encoder files available on github repo of CoretinJ real time voice cloning. Then do : python demo_toolbox.py and you get the GUI or python demo_cli.py to use CLI.

Answer (score 0):

your pip/pip3 and python/python3 is not the same path/executable! had the same error!

Answer (score -1):

Solution: I didn't know I have to use Anaconda Prompt for running `python demo_cli.py`. Then it works.